# running 2 methods with defined instance variables but still coming up with undefined local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, instance-variables, nameerror

I'm a beginner and I've tried looking through all my online resources. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong even though I'm adding the "@" symbols so that the 'title' and 'author' variable applies the the second method (description.) Not sure why running this code comes up with a NameError - undefined local variable or method `title' for #. Any ideas? Thank you

```
class Book
  def set_title_and_author(title,author)
    @title = title  
    @author = author
  end  

  def description
    puts "#{title} was written by #{author}" 
  end
end
```

here are some specs:

```
describe "Book" do
  describe "description" do
    it "should return title and author in description" do
      book = Book.new
      book.set_title_and_author("Ender's Game","Orson Scott Card")
      expect( book.description ).to eq("Ender's Game was written by Orson Scott Card")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Tagging which language this is will help it get answers.

Comment: When you '@' before variables rails understand it as instance variables available in that instance of class. So to access title and author you could do this `puts "#{@title} was written by #{@author}"` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the @ when setting and when getting an instance variable:

```
class Book
  def set_title_and_author(title, author)
    @title = title  
    @author = author
  end  

  def description
    puts "#{@title} was written by #{@author}" 
  end
end
```

Comment: That fixed it. I'm a jackass. I would upvote you but my reputation is too low =[

Thank you very much!

Comment: No need for an upvote, just accept the answer if it solved the problem.